# Distributive Property of the Multiplication of Modulo Functions

Tags: modular-arithmetic, fractional-part

According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Properties_(identities)), $ab \bmod n = [(a \bmod n)(b \bmod n)] \bmod n$. However $(x \bmod 1)^2 \neq (x^2 \bmod1)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. So, is there some way to multiply modulo functions to make functions that is valid for all reals?

Comment: $\Bbb Z$ is not an ideal of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but I don't know what that means nor how it relates to my question. Could you explain what you mean?

Comment: The article assumes that $a,b,n$ are all integers. The identity may not be valid for non-integer values. What are you trying to do with modulo functions?

Comment: @Somos I want to multipy two of the modulo functions together to create a function of the form $c \bmod 1$, where $c$ is some elementary function (like a polynomial) without the mod function in it.

Comment: What you ask for does not exist. You just found an example of that. $(x \bmod 1)^2 \neq (p(x) \bmod1)$ for any polynomial $p(x)$.

Comment: @Somos Oh, ok then.